# NodeJS API get Items array of items pro each category

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api

Good day,

could you please advice how is possible to create for each category the list of items that belong only to this category like this format:

```
[
    {
        "id": category1,
        "name": "Category1",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": product1,
                "name": product1.name
                "images": [
                    {
                        "id": product1,
                        "url": product1.img,

                    },

        ]
        },
        {
        "id": category2,
        "name": "Category2",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": product2,
                "name": product.name
                "images": [
                    {
                        "id": product2,
                        "url": product2.img,
                    }]
            },
            {
                "id": product3,
                "name": product3.name
                "images": [
                    {
                        "id": product3,
                        "url": product3.img,
                    }]
            }      
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is the request to database:

```
connection.query("SELECT productId, productName, productImg, productCategoryId, ProductCategoryName FROM Items", function (err, tmpres) { }

if (err) {
    console.log("query failed!" + err);
    return res.json(500, err);
}

var data = [];

tmpres.forEach(function (a) {
    data.push({
        id: a.productCategoryId,
        title: a.productName
        ....
});

res.json(data);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a syntax error. You close your callback function immediately `function (err, tmpres) { }`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create that array, however this can have perfomance issues when your list grows.

I have an altenative, using an object instead of array.

```
 var data = {};

tmpres.forEach(function(a) {
  if (data[a.productCategoryId]) {
    data[a.productCategoryId].products.push({
      productId: a.productId,
      productName: a.productName,
      productImg: a.productImg
    });
  } else {
    data[a.productCategoryId] = {
      id: a.productCategoryId,
      title: a.productName,
      products: [
        {
          productId: a.productId,
          productName: a.productName,
          productImg: a.productImg
        }
      ]
    };
  }
});


// loop data

for (var key of Object.keys(data)) {
  console.log("id: " + key + " -> " + data[key].products) // productCategoryId and array of products
}
```

If it is not necessary to use an array, this can work alright.